# Parsing a JSON file from a URL

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps-api-3

Beginner developer here. I'm trying to build a Web App that displays things like the current time, weather, and news. I'm trying to use the Google Distance Matrix API to calculate commute time and distance.

The following URL spits out JSON, i'm trying to find a way to parse that file and display it in HTML if that makes any sense. I only need the commute time and distance.

Here is an example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY

```
var units = IMPERIAL
origins = address1
destinations = destination1
apiKey = MY_API_KEY
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units="       + units + "&origins=" + origins + "&destinations=" + destinations + "&key=" +apiKey;
```

Comment: You can try something like this: http://json2html.com/

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I would use an ajax call to retrieve addition data. I use the JQuery solution ([link to the api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). For the situation you described, be sure to set the `dataType` option to `"json"`. You use the `success` option to handle the returned data, which, in your case, is the JSON.